# How Can I Deactivate iTunes When The Hard Drive Crashed?

Tags: hard-drive, itunes

My hard drive crashed, so I got a new physical drive and instead of Vista I installed Windows 7 Ultimate - not a restore from backup type of recovery.   I reinstalled iTunes and I copied over, from a recent NAS backup, my former iTunes directory..

When I go into iTunes it says that I have another computer activated (the broken hard drive) and that I have 3 activations left.   Not a huge deal since I am usually active on one or two machines anyway BUT, how I can deactivate an iTunes account on a broken hard drive?   Did I miss something in the copy of the old iTunes folders from the most recent backup?  A registry setting?  A hidden something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this](http://creativebits.org/deauthorizing_itunes) out. I have used it a few times. You basically don't worry about it until you have used all 5 up. Then you just re-authorize.

Comment: Ah!  Well thank you!  I will worry about it if and when I ever get to 5 then.  If I find myself in the hands of Apple Support prior to getting to 5, I will ask as the others on there said they did.  Cool!